Need help deciphering word written in Fraktur
I am trying to decipher this word and am having a hard time since I do not read Fraktur too well.
Also, what does it mean translated into English?


The word is "Proselyten". It is the plural form of the singular "Proselyt" and it means the same as in English ("proselyte"): converts from another religion. Originally it was used in the Septuagint and meant a convert to Judaism, the meaning was later generalized to mean a convert to a new religion or doctrine in general.
The word is of Greek (Koine) origin: "προσήλυτος" (transliterated, "proselytos").

And there are two variants of the small letter "s": The one that looks modern, used in word endings like "das"; and the one that is long and could be compared to the integral sign ∫, which indeed is a stylized "s", used in the other cases, as in "Proselyten" (probably because it lends itself better to ligatures like "sz and "ss", and to kerning). The "long s" is very similar to the "f" (especially in the text font, as opposed to the title font).

There is a short list of fraktur letters that can be confusing in this answer:
What is this font called and how to study it
The "long s" looks like an "f", and the "y" looks like a "n". The "P" looks like a "B".
As the previous poster noted, the word is Proselyten.

In the first instance of the word the "Prose" bit made no problem to me. It is the "lyt" bit where I had to give up and look at the answer. There are also different styles of Fraktur-like fonts and one can bu used to a different one (e.g., Schwabacher - here these two letters are more usual: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwabacher#/media/File:Fraktur_alte_schwabacher.png ) After all, many other languages, like English, used the long ſ in the same way.
